# Is the following sintax rfc 3261 compatible?

Tags: sip, rfc, abnf

could you please tell me if the following syntax is compatible with rfc3261? Thanks.

401 Unauthorized:

```
Digest realm="movistar.tel",\r\n   nonce="35e21fba60422a1f2D6a1fde23235c885d287d50e45fd49d56a354",\r\n   algorithm=MD5,\r\n   qop="auth"
```

or should be

```
Digest realm="movistar.tel",nonce="35e21fba60422a1f2D6a1fde23235c885d287d50e45fd49d56a354",algorithm=MD5,qop="auth"
```

I'm trying to analyze using "https://github.com/nygge/abnfc/blob/master/samples/sip/rfc3261.abnf" without success.

Please, can  you help me to understand this?. Sorry my bad english.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is defined in section 25.1 of [rfc3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261)

In most place CRLF can be added for readability. Make sur at least a WSP is located right after this CRLF. This helps to differentiate new headers from LWS when parsing.

```
SIP header field values can be folded onto multiple lines if the
continuation line begins with a space or horizontal tab.  All linear
white space, including folding, has the same semantics as SP.  A
recipient MAY replace any linear white space with a single SP before
interpreting the field value or forwarding the message downstream.
This is intended to behave exactly as HTTP/1.1 as described in RFC
2616 [8].  The SWS construct is used when linear white space is
optional, generally between tokens and separators.

   LWS  =  [*WSP CRLF] 1*WSP ; linear whitespace
   SWS  =  [LWS] ; sep whitespace
```

CONCLUSION: both lines seems to be valid.